# cURL error 2: easy handle already used in multi handle (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) Google Client Access Token

Tags: php, yii2, libcurl, php-curl, google-client

I am using google Authentication using GoogleClient on my website. when I am trying to get Google access token with Auth code I am getting the following error.

```
$accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code'])
```

This is the error

```
cURL error 2: easy handle already used in multi handle (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

**Please help me.**

Comment: Guys, I found the solution. working fine for me. Thanks.

Comment: what was the solution? I'm having the same problem with a MailChimp connection

Comment: @AntoineHolman Please see the Answer I wrote below.

Answer (score 2):

I am posting my solution here.

**Problem:**

In my case I guess, when my server auto-update something it affected some functionality to handle multiple cUrl requests.

**Solution:**

I am using **Yii Framework** and I am using **guzzlehttp** vendor in my project. this module was raising this issue. so I commented a piece of code to solve the issue.

Open the file.
vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php

Go to the function **release**

and comment the following lines.

```
if (count($this->handles) >= $this->maxHandles) {
   curl_close($resource);
} else {
   // Remove all callback functions as they can hold onto references
   // and are not cleaned up by curl_reset. Using curl_setopt_array
   // does not work for some reason, so removing each one
   // individually.
   curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, null);
   curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, null);
   curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, null);
   curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, null);
   curl_reset($resource);
   $this->handles[] = $resource;
}
```

and Add the following line instead

```
curl_close($resource);
```

See the complete Function after applying solution.

```
public function release(EasyHandle $easy)
{
    $resource = $easy->handle;
    unset($easy->handle);

    /*if (count($this->handles) >= $this->maxHandles) {
        curl_close($resource);
    } else {
        // Remove all callback functions as they can hold onto references
        // and are not cleaned up by curl_reset. Using curl_setopt_array
        // does not work for some reason, so removing each one
        // individually.
        curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, null);
        curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, null);
        curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, null);
        curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, null);
        curl_reset($resource);
        $this->handles[] = $resource;
    }*/
    curl_close($resource);
}
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Go to server and serch EasyApache 4 and click customize and left side  look in php extention click now and select php version , search curl and unistall the curl
 your error solve